# Fin vs flipper?

Tags: word-usage, terminology, science

What is the difference between fins and flippers?

While my own intuition says that a fin would be fixed (like, a shark's dorsal fin), and a flipper could be moved about way more (like a turtle's flippers), the following wikipedia page suggests that fins may be on fish and flippers on mammals and others. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fin_and_flipper_locomotion

Both translate to the same word in my native language German.

Which is correct?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure. [The answer here](http://www.italki.com/question/92072) claims dolphins have both fins and flippers.

Answer (score 6):

The technical difference is that a flipper is a modified limb and a fin is not.  So a dolphin has a fin on his back and flippers where a mammal's forelimbs are.

With this, most fish would have only fins, aside from the lungfish which have leggy fins to walk on land.  Sea turtles would have flippers.

Answer (score 3):

*Flipper* (like *[fluke](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=fluke#F5207400)*) is more restricted than *[fin](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fin)*, which ODO defines as

> A flattened appendage on various parts of the body of many aquatic vertebrates, including fish and cetaceans, and some invertebrates, used for propelling, steering, and balancing.

as opposed to *[flipper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flipper)*,

> A broad flat limb without fingers, used for swimming by various sea animals such as seals, whales, and turtles.

The terms *flipper* and *fluke* are almost never used to describe parts of fish, even when the appendages are fleshy, as with [shark fins](http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/in-china-victory-for-wildlife-conservation-as-citizens-persuaded-to-give-up-shark-fin-soup/2013/10/19/e8181326-3646-11e3-89db-8002ba99b894_story.html), or lobed, as with lungfish, which indeed are known as *[lobe-finned fish](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/museums-static/obl4he/vertebratediversity/lobefinned_fishes.html)*.

For cetaceans, many people use *fin* and *flipper* interchangeably, but in more formal discussions of anatomy, references to *dorsal fins*, *pectoral flippers*, and *tail flukes* are most common. *Dorsal flippers* is far rarer, not turning up at all in a Google Ngram search. *Pectoral fins* appears to be similarly rare in reference to mammals, although this is difficult to establish, as fish do have *pectoral fins*, and not only fish but aircraft and [Cadillacs](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:59svl.JPG) have *tail fins* as well.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up your claim that for cetaceans *fin* and *flipper* are used interchangeably?

Comment: @Araucaria See e.g. "pectoral fin" on pages from the [Hawaii Wildlife Fund](http://wildhawaii.org/marinelife/whale_behavior.html), the [AMNH](http://www.amnh.org/explore/news-blogs/on-exhibit-posts/sperm-whales-amazing-adaptations), [NSW Environment & Heritage](http://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/animals/humpbackwhale.htm), the [CBC](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/humpback-whale-entangled-by-ropes-sought-by-rescuers-1.2781588), and the [UCSD Birch Aquarium](http://www.aquarium.ucsd.edu/Education/Public_Programs/Outdoor_Adventures/Whale_Watching/Weekly_Update/).